# mouseEntered event disabled when mouseDown (NSEvents Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouseevent, nsbutton, nsevent

I have created an NSButton class, and when rolling over my buttons it happily detects mouseEntered and mouseExited events. But as soon as the mouseDown event occurs, so long as the mouse it down, mouseEntered events are no longer called until the mouse button is lifted.

So, when the mouseDown event is called, mouseEntered or MouseExited events are no longer called, nor is mouseDown called when rolling over other buttons until I let go of the initial mouseDown.

So I would like to detect when my mouse enters while the mouse is down as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag to my NSTrackingAreaOptions. mouseEntered and mouseExited events now fire when dragging with mouse down.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to mention _in your question_ that you were using an `NSTrackingArea`.

Comment: That still helped me.

Comment: Hm this isn't working for me. I'm using `NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag`.

Answer (score 5):

When an `NSButton` receives a mouse down event, it enters a [private tracking loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW4), handling all the mouse events that are posted until it gets a mouse up. You can set up your own tracking loop to do things based on the mouse location:

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {

    BOOL keepTracking = YES;
    NSEvent * nextEvent = event;

    while( keepTracking ){

        NSPoint mouseLocation = [self convertPoint:[nextEvent locationInWindow]
                                          fromView:nil];
        BOOL mouseInside = [self mouse:mouseLocation inRect:[self bounds]];
        // Draw highlight conditional upon mouse being in bounds
        [self highlight:mouseInside];

        switch( [nextEvent type] ){
            case NSLeftMouseDragged:
                /* Do something interesting, testing mouseInside */
                break;
            case NSLeftMouseUp:
                if( mouseInside ) [self performClick:nil];
                keepTracking = NO;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        nextEvent = [[self window] nextEventMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the left mouse button is down, dragging begins. If I remember correctly, mouse moved events aren't sent during drags, and that's probably one reason that you don't get `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` messages. However, if you implement the `NSDraggingDestination` protocol and register your view as a possible recipient of the type of data being dragged, you'll get `draggingEntered` and `draggingExited` messages instead.

Read about it in the [Dragging Destinations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000977-BAJBJFBG) section of *Drag and Drop Programming Topics*.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to get this going. Its all very focused on dragging different data types. Im not dragging any data. I simply want to detect when the mouse enters a new view (is dragged (mouse down) across nsbuttons).